# Convention to label components in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, circuit-design, schematics

Given an un-labeled schematic like the below, is there a convention on how to label the various components?

[image]

For example, would the 'top-left' resistor be R1? Would the one to the right of it be R2, or the one branching downward from it, etc. Are there conventions for this, or it just comes up to 'label it however you want' ?

Comment: You can even start with R100 , then if next PCB , R200, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a schematic, I would generally label components left-to-right and top-to-bottom, while trying to keep parts in a logical block together.  For example, in a multi-stage amplifier, stage 1 might have R1 - R5, and stage 2 has R6 - R10, even if that violates the left to right and top down rule.

Often, once a PC board is designed, the components are re-labeled left to right and top down on the PC board, then that numbering is back-annotated to the schematic.  This may mess up the order on the schematic, but makes it easier to find parts on the PC board.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard convention, or even a widely-used ad hoc approach.

These labels are called reference designators. You must make sure that the first letter is correct for the type of component being labeled...that much is standardized.

Do not reuse reference designations...if you delete R1 from the schematic you should never have another R1. You should also maintain a list, somewhere on the drawing, of reference designators that are not used because their corresponding components have been removed.

Comment: When you say "delete", I assume you mean components removed in future PCB revisions? Or every single time you delete a component from the schematic software?

Comment: If you revise a schematic, such that an old resistor was deleted somewhere and a new resistor was added somewhere else, you shouldn't reuse the reference designator. That causes problems with the BOM, troubleshooting instructions, assembly, etc.

Comment: And I guess I mean on any version of the schematic that is given to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. And I think the RefDes being relatively ordered and close in number matters more on the layout than the schematic. On the schematic all components associated with that part of the circuit are already right there in front of me. On the PCB, if I am looking for C15, and I see C14, C17, or C18 first then I expect C15 to be nearby and not across the board. It doesn't matter to me if all those caps are far apart from each other on the schematic and associated with completely different parts of the circuit.